# Find Wifi encryption type

Tags: linux, shell-script, wifi, nmcli

While I working on a shell script, I need to display SSID,Passphrase,Encryption-type of connected wifi. I got SSID & Passphrase in output but I unable to display encryption-type.

Which command will work? I'm working on ubuntu 18.04. I want to print using cli..

Here I'm atteching output of `nmcli device wifi list`:

```
IN-USE  SSID                   MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        CoreFragment           Infra  10    130 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        COMFAST                Infra  10    135 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA1      
*       CoreFragment_5G        Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        Yash Shah              Infra  10    270 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        Appbirds_Technologies  Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        dlink                  Infra  2     54 Mbit/s   49      ▂▄__  WEP       
        REDWING LABS_5G        Infra  149   270 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        REDWING LABS           Infra  4     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        20096641               Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   32      ▂▄__  --        
        LIFEKYOR PHARMA        Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Frankpro               Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1
```

Comment: encryption type like wpa-psk,wpa2,etc..

Comment: I just want to print encryption type only but I don't know from where I'll get it

Comment: Isn't it the last column in your output?

Comment: yes.. but I want to print using command

Comment: Try using  `iwconfig`

Comment: I didn't find in iwconfig @RuiFRibeiro  is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can print the desired fields directly from `nmcli`, without the need for any other command.

From the manual:

> ```
> -f | --fields {[field...] | all | common}
>      This option is used to specify what fields (column names) should be printed.
> ```

So, you can use:

```
nmcli -f SECURITY device wifi list
```

---

Consider using terse output with `-t`:

> ```
> -t | --terse
>      Output is terse. This mode is designed and suitable for computer (script) processing.
> ```

```
nmcli -t -f SECURITY device wifi list
```

---

To display only connected WIFI use something like this:

```
nmcli -t -f IN-USE,SECURITY device wifi list | grep '^\*' | colrm 1 2
```

Comment: It showing like:  WPA1 WPA2
WPA1
WPA1 WPA2
WPA2
WPA1 WPA2
WEP
WPA1 WPA2
WPA1 WPA2
 but I want to display connected wifi only.